# Doctrine 2: Update query with query builder

Tags: php, sql, database, doctrine

Hi
I've got the following query but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$q = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->update('models\User', 'u')
    ->set('u.username', $username)
    ->set('u.email', $email)
    ->where('u.id = ?1')
    ->setParameter(1, $editId)
    ->getQuery();
$p = $q->execute();
```

This returns the following error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException'
>   with message '[Semantical Error] line
>   0, col 38 near 'testusername WHERE':
>   Error: 'testusername' is not defined.'
>   in ...

I would be glad of any help

Answer (score 176, accepted):

I think you need to use `->set()` It's much safer to make all your values parameters:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$query = $queryBuilder->update('models\User', 'u')
        ->set('u.username', ':userName')
        ->set('u.email', ':email')
        ->where('u.id = :editId')
        ->setParameter('userName', $userName)
        ->setParameter('email', $email)
        ->setParameter('editId', $editId)
        ->getQuery();
$result = $query->execute();
```

Comment: You should always pass your variables as parameter to the Doctrine query!

Comment: you can also ``use $qb->update(…)->set('u.username', $qb->createNamedParameter($username))`` and omit the ->setParameter part. That's IMO the nicest way. A similar method is ``-> createPositionalParameter()``. See http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#binding-parameters-to-placeholders

Comment: It's even not "you should" - you must use `setParameter` otherwise use get `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 80: Error: Expected Literal, got '*'` error.

Answer (score 13):

Let's say there is an administrator dashboard where users are listed with their id printed as a data attribute so it can be retrieved at some point via JavaScript.

An update could be executed this way …

```
class UserRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function updateUserStatus($userId, $newStatus)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->update()
            ->set('u.isActive', '?1')
            ->setParameter(1, $qb->expr()->literal($newStatus))
            ->where('u.id = ?2')
            ->setParameter(2, $qb->expr()->literal($userId))
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleScalarResult()
        ;
    }
```

*AJAX* action handling:

```
# Post datas may be:
# handled with a specific custom formType — OR — retrieved from request object
$userId = (int)$request->request->get('userId');
$newStatus = (int)$request->request->get('newStatus');
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$r = $em->getRepository('NAMESPACE\User')
        ->updateUserStatus($userId, $newStatus);
if ( !empty($r) ){
    # Row updated
}
```

Working example using Doctrine 2.5 *(on top of Symfony3)*.

Answer (score 4):

With a small change, it worked fine for me

```
$qb=$this->dm->createQueryBuilder('AppBundle:CSSDInstrument')
               ->update()
               ->field('status')->set($status)
               ->field('id')->equals($instrumentId)
               ->getQuery()
               ->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the code is to be written in the repository,

then no need to specify the entity name,

Just alias `u` will work

```
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->update()
        ->set('u.username', ':userName')
        ->set('u.email', ':email')
        ->where('u.id = :editId')
        ->setParameter('userName', $userName)
        ->setParameter('email', $email)
        ->setParameter('editId', $editId)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
```

Comment: FYI: Alias can be any other letter, word