# Constructing UPDATE statements using associative arrays in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What is the best way to construct an UPDATE statement using associative arrays in PHP?

For example, say I have a function like so:

```
/**
 * For update queries
 * 
 * @param string $tableName Name of the table we're wanting to update.
 * @param array $values Associative array of columns / values to update. e.g. array('name' => 'John', 'age' => 29)
 * @param array $conditions Associative array of conditions. e.g. array('user_id' => 1) equates to "WHERE user_id = 1"
 */
 public function update($tableName, $values, $conditions = array()){
      //Construct SQL
 }
```

So far, I've been able to construct simple UPDATE statements such as:

```
UPDATE `myTableName` SET `name` = :name, `age` = :age WHERE `user_id` = :user_id
```

Now I'm left wondering: What is the best way to approach constructing the WHERE clause? Are there similar implementations in other libraries and code bases that I can look into? For example: How do I approach the construction of WHERE clauses that have OR and AND and IN() etc?

```
UPDATE example SET col = :val WHERE user_id = :user_id AND (age = :age OR name = :name)
```

Comment: This might by helpful: [**Can I bind an array to an in condition**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)

Answer (score 1):

```
public function update($tableName, $values, $conditions = array()) {
    if (empty($values)) {
        throw new Exception('Nothing to update');
    }
    $valueStrings = array();
    foreach ($values as $name => $value) {
        $valueStrings[] = $name . ' = :' . $name;
    }
    $conditionStrings = array();
    foreach ($conditions as $column => $value) {
        $conditionString = $column;
        $conditionString .= is_array($value)
            ? ('IN ("' . implode('","', $value) . '")')
            : (' = "' . $value . '"')
        ;
        $conditionStrings[] = $conditionString;
    }
    $sql = 'UPDATE ' . $tableName
        . ' SET ' . implode(', ', $valueStrings)
        . ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $conditionStrings)
    ;
    // execute query
}
```

But actually you should use an ORM for that:

[Doctrine 2: Update query with query builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337751/doctrine-2-update-query-with-query-builder)

Comment: It helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple solution would be to use `implode()` using 'AND' as the separator:

```
$columnCArrayValues = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$conditions = array(
    'column_a = :column_a',
    'column_b <> :column_b',
    'column_c IN (' . implode(',', $columnCArrayValues) . ')'
);

// ..

$where = '(' implode(') AND (', $conditions) . ')';
// result: (column_a = :column_a) AND (column_b <> :column_b) 
// AND (column_c IN (1,2,3,4))
```

Alternatively, the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) has a really nice [Db](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.html) component in [both](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/index.html#zend-db) versions of the framework.