# mysql UPDATE statements using associative arrays in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, associative-array

I has been read this topic [Constructing UPDATE statements using associative arrays in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269067/constructing-update-statements-using-associative-arrays-in-php) , but it was a bit different with what I need to.

I have a table `t1`.

```
+--------------+----------------+----------------+------------+
| money        | exp            | uid            | remark     |
+--------------+----------------+----------------+------------+
| 9999         | 9999           | 1              |            |
| 1234         | 567            | 2              |            |
| 8887         | 88             | 3              |            |
+--------------+----------------+----------------+------------+
```

I would like to create a PHP `function` called `jnupdateuser` to update this table, like:

```
jnupdateuser(array('money'=>10000,'exp'=>10000),1);
```

After that the data will be this:

```
+--------------+----------------+----------------+------------+
| money        | exp            | uid            | remark     |
+--------------+----------------+----------------+------------+
| 10000        | 10000          | 1              |            |
| 1234         | 567            | 2              |            |
| 8887         | 88             | 3              |            |
+--------------+----------------+----------------+------------+
```

If do with this:

`jnupdateuser(array('remark'=>'None'),2);`

than the data will be this:

```
+--------------+----------------+----------------+------------+
| money        | exp            | uid            | remark     |
+--------------+----------------+----------------+------------+
| 9999         | 9999           | 1              |            |
| 1234         | 567            | 2              | None       |
| 8887         | 88             | 3              |            |
+--------------+----------------+----------------+------------+
```

My code as below:

```
function jnupdateuser($jnparams = array(),$uids){

    $conditionStrings = array();
    foreach ($jnparams as $column => $value) {
        //how to create this part to update my table? or maybe I was totally wrong?
    }

    return DB::query("UPDATE ".DB::table('game_jnmx_user')." SET ??? = ??? WHERE uid = $uids "); 
}
```

`DB::query` is my template language, same as `mysqli_query`, `DB::table` also template language;

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe something like `$set = 'SET '; foreach ($jnparams as $column => $value) { $set .= $column . " = '$value', "; } $set = rtrim(', ', $set);`  then use `$set` in the query. Check that `$jnparams` is set first though. This also doesn't look at multiple security issues this opens

Comment: Oh, the `rtrim` is backwards http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php. `$set` should be first.

Comment: And why can't you adapt the code in that question to your use case?  Seems the only difference is the table name.   There are also plenty of query builders already out there, did you try to use one or examine the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
function jnupdateuser ($jnparams = [], $uid)
{
    if (empty($jnparams)) {
        return true;
    }

    $conditions = [];
    $uid = (int) $uid;

    foreach ($jnparams as $column => $value) {
        $conditions[] = "`{$column}` = '{$value}'";
    }

    $conditions = implode(',', $conditions);

    return DB::query("UPDATE ".DB::table('game_jnmx_user')." SET {$conditions} WHERE uid = {$uid}");
}
```

It builds the SET from the input parameters and I added some validations. Be ware that here you should escape or sanitize in some way the data you put into the DB, cause it's vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: I'd really recommend not writing solutions that are subject to SQL injections to prevent future beginners from copying and using your code...

Comment: Without knowing his DB abstraction I cannot escape the values correctly. If he's using mysqli underneath - I don't have the connection resource to use for escaping. Same with PDO. I can try to use a method which can try to escape them, but it won't be the same as using the DB for that and the answer will get way longer than it should have :D

Comment: Refer to your answer, my final is like this:

`function jnupdateuser($jnparams = array(),$uids){
 foreach ($jnparams as $column => $value) {
  $a = 0;
  $set[$a] = addslashes($column)." = '".addslashes(($value))."' ";
  $a++;
 }
 $uids = intval($uids);
 $lset = implode(',',$set);
 return DB::query("UPDATE ".DB::table('game_jnmx_user')." SET $lset WHERE uid = $uids");
}`
, is it any SQL injection?

Comment: @SweeHong from PHP Docs for addslashes: `The addslashes() is sometimes incorrectly used to try to prevent SQL Injection. Instead, database-specific escaping functions and/or prepared statements should be used.`

Comment: Actually, my template language got other statement to prevent SQL injection, `daddslashes()`, since this is not a famous template language, so I didn't use in my question to avoid confusion.

Comment: @SweeHong then use that instead of the raw `addslashes` :)

Comment: @vuryss Thank you. :D